Unable to process the type of data structure returned by Supabase database
I am using Edge Functions written in Typescript fetch data from my table in Supabase database. Unable to understand how I am supposed to process the returned request. Coding in VS Code, I have no idea the type of data structure I am receiving. Looked around the supabase docs and found an example but still could not process the data accurately.
Fetching the data and processing
const portfolioResponse = await supabase
                  .from('portfolios')
                  .select()
                  .eq("user_id", userId);
const portfolioMap = portfolioResponse.data;
const portfolio = portfolioMap.first;

Example data response from supabase docs
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Michael",
      "address": {
        "postcode": 90210
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}

I logged the type of the concstant portfolioMap but it only retrieves Object object. I also confirmed if the Supabase client was authenticated and working perfectly and it is.
Error log
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

I want to access data from the constant portfolio but it is deemed as undefined
How do I process the data to access the columns from my table?

Looks like simple JSON array there?
